# Tornar um site com várias páginas offline

Tags: html, html5

Supondo que eu tenha um site com várias páginas - por exemplo um blog - quero colocar uma opção para quem o visitar possa ter acesso a ele sem internet.

Como nem todo dispositivo tem acesso constante a internet, e nem todo lugar há essa possibilidade, isso possibilitaria o usuário ler um texto enquanto está em uma dessas situações.

Porém, baseado nisso há algumas implicações:

- *Há uma solução que exija menos do usuário?* Instruir ele a abrir o menu do navegador e salvar a página - opção que não há em alguns navegadores móveis - não seria uma boa ideia.
- *É possível fazer disso uma opção para o usuário?* Não quero que meu site faça a franquia de uso de internet de alguém estourar assim que abri-lo carregando todos os artigos do site;
- *É possível que o usuário selecione o que ele quer salvar?* Por exemplo, um artigo, ou ainda um conjunto de artigos, que ele se interessou em ler;
- *Imagens e vídeos nas postagens podem ser salvos?*

Comment: em teoria isso depende do navegador do cliente... mas configurando os headers da pagina para cache total com esses headers..
lembrando que tem que remover qualquer conteudo dinamico da pagina, como analitics e outros..

Comment: Olhe meus comentários para a resposta do @gabriel-gartz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No HTML5 existe a api [Application Cache](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html), que se trata exatamente de manipular o cache para ter uma aplicação que funciona em modo offline. Leia-se, que pode ser instalada no browser do usuário.

Trata-se de uma API que permite você adicionar um arquivo de manifesto que vai controlar o cache da sua aplicação. Porém é muito extenso para explicar detalhadamente aqui como funciona e como utilizar.

Além da [especificação oficial](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html) eu vou deixar alguns links de recomendação para estudo:

- http://sergiolopes.org/palestra-appcache-html5-offline/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp (em inglês)

Você pode criar um IFRAME com o manifesto, instalando assim sua aplicação, colocando em um botão, você pode adicionar também o manifesto só depois que a pessoa realizar uma ação na página, como clicar em um botão de instalação, adicionando o manifesto e salvando em cookie para que quando recarregada seja adicionado o manifesto automaticamente quando já instalado.

Quanto ao cache seletivo de arquivos, o que você deve fazer é um manifesto dinâmico, de forma que determinadas opções que seu usuário escolher você irá modificar o manifesto para que este faça cache dos arquivos desejado. Porém isso vai fazer com que recarregue todos os arquivos do manifesto, então use com cuidado.

Existem outras maneiras mais escusas de manipular o sistema de cahce de aplicativos, mas se você pretende usar instalar e remover vídeos eu recomendo usar `IFRAME` com manifesto exclusivo (no caso do Firefox cada um vai pedir autorização para instalação a primeira vez, o que está descrito na especificação porém outros browsers não respeitam ainda).

Comment: Ela não atende os pontos 2, 3 e parte da 4: não é uma escolha do usuário, baixa tudo o que há no manifesto e não baixa vídeos (ao menos no que vi ainda não). Me interessei na resposta do @BrenoZan porque parece que, com ajuda do código no servidor, esses pontos podem ser atendidos.

Comment: Ah, me lembrei outro problema do Application Cache: ela foi criada para sites de uma só página, não sites com muitas páginas: um blog pode chegar a ter centenas. Imagine o tamanho do `manifest.appcache`!

Comment: Também pode ser usado em várias página, basta todas elas terem referencia para o mesmo manifesto e no manifesto incluir a URL de todas as páginas que deseja fazer o cache, fora isso, você pode fazer cache da página de entrada e utilizar o header de cache-control para que as paginas subsequentes se mantenham acessíveis offline, utilize alguma ferramenta que varra seus diretórios para gerar o manifesto automaticamente. Sim se você quer fazer cache de uma aplicação grande, vai armazenar muita informação no cliente e vai dificultar seu controle entre online/offline. Não existe solução mágica.

Comment: Já viu aquelas questões que o próprio autor responde? Essa ia ser uma delas, mas você está quase chegando na minha resposta. Na verdade eu procurava por alguém que tinha feito isso de maneira mais organizada, mas ao visto ninguém fez. Coloque só a página principal e um `FALLBACK` no manifesto e salve os textos e imagens no `IndexedDB`: você me sugeriu o mesmo truque que já estou usando.

Comment: Bom, eu tentei responder a sua pergunta da melhor forma possível que eu conheço e ainda fui atras de algumas fontes pra vc poder ler sobre o assunto, na sua pergunta não explicava que você queria uma alternativa a Application Cache do HTML5, ainda dei sugestões de como resolver problemas pontuais que você apresentou, quais não são previstos pelo Application Cache, de fato ele não foi feito para sites dinâmicos e para aplicações, daí o nome dele, mas fiz o meu melhor pra elucidar a questão.

Comment: Na verdade não procuro uma alternativa, porém alguém que tinha uma melhor aplicação dela ao invés do yadda yadda "coloque as páginas no manifesto e a tag no <html>". Propronho uma edição do seu ou crio uma resposta do zero?

Answer (score 3):

Usar o [Application Cache](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html), introduzido no HTML5, seria a primeira ideia a ser pensada.
Em um site com uma ou duas páginas isso funciona bem e sem prejudicar a experiência do usuário: são poucos arquivos a serem baixados, não há muitas escolhas a serem feitas e nem motivos para se preocupar com gasto de banda.

Porém sites com várias páginas usá-lo gera alguns problemas: *alto tráfego, muitas páginas no manifesto, entre outros*. Porém podemos aproveitar de que eles geralmente são gerados por algum programa ou script usando em dados de algum banco: *ao invés de armazenar com o HTML gerado usamos e armazenamos os dados*.

O HTML5 introduziu várias formas de armazenamento de dados: basicamente todo navegador que suporta o Application Cache também irá suportar, no mínimo WebSQL ou IndexedDB ([fonte](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps,indexeddb,websql)). Com isso podemos armazenar os dados do site - sejam eles texto, imagens ou vídeo - quando o usuário pedir e trabalhar com eles independente de uma conexão a internet.

Usando a opção `FALLBACK` do Application Cache todas as páginas que não estão no manifesto serão redirecionadas a que você especificar. Assim, só redirecionar todas as páginas para uma onde serão processadas por uma biblioteca MVC: poucos arquivos no manifesto bastam.

*Caso você esteja lendo isso no futuro* já vemos que o Application Cache está sendo superado por outras tecnologias, no momento os [ServiceWorkers](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md): ao invés de você configurar uma página, com um script nela que irá gerar as demais, você usa um SharedWorker para tal. Isso parece simples, mas há grandes mudanças: ser controlado pelo JavaScript, sem a necessidade de usar `<iframe>`s; a opção de desativar ele se quiser; a capacidade de usar a conexão quando ela estiver disponível e quando não usar outra fonte de dados.

Comment: +1 não conhecia o ServiceWorker. Bem interessante.

Comment: Quando escrevi essa resposta falei que um supera o outro, na verdade somente nessa utilização uma vez que o Application Cache funciona bem para o que foi feito, só não para grandes aplicativos. Ao menos no futuro não vamos precisar desses truques.